# Use "named parameters" in ibase_execute php-function

Tags: php, firebird, named-parameters

I have connected to `firebird DB` with `interbase.so`.

On manual page http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-execute.php there is an example:

```
<?php
function db_execute($stmt,$data)
{
    if(!is_array($data))
        return ibase_execute($stmt,$data);
    array_unshift($data,$stmt);
    $rc=call_user_func_array('ibase_execute',$data);
    return $rc;
}
?>
```

How to prepare query with named parameters and bind these parameters with values? eg. here http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#example-1004

Comment: Firebird itself does not have named bind parameters, if the driver supports them (which I don't know), then it would be a translation provided by the driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Firebird pdo driver and the named parameters example should work , here is one example

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO testuser (ID, NAME, ADDRESS, COMPANY) VALUES (:ID, :NAME, :ADDRESS, :COMPANY)';
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$values = array(
    ':ID'      => 2,
    ':NAME'    => 'user2',
    ':ADDRESS' => 'address2',
    ':COMPANY' => 'company2'
);
if ($stmt->execute($values) === false) {
    var_dump($db->errorInfo());
} else {
    print_r($db->query('SELECT * FROM testuser')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
}
```